# Adding realistic noise to a gaussian distribution while keeping the number of samples above/below a threshold approximately constant

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, normal-distribution

I have a normal distribution and a threshold function that determines if a value is true.

I'd like to add noise to the truth values, such that the further above/below the threshold the less likely the value is to be inverted.  Thus at the extremes perhaps there is a 1% chance of a flip, and right at the threshold there is a 50% chance.

I would also like to keep the number of samples above and below the threshold approximately constant before and after the noise is added.

The below code I think does the first half, but not certain as to the approach for the second half. (perhaps trial subtraction of a delta from rnum, till sum of trues before and after the operation is within some error margin)

```
import numpy as np

mean = .5
std_dev = .2
num_points = 10000

arr =  np.sort( np.random.normal(loc=mean, scale= std_dev, size=(num_points)) )

threshold = .8

trues = arr >= threshold

temp = np.where(trues, 1-arr, arr)
scaling = max(temp)
temp *= .5/scaling

rnum = np.random.random(size=(num_points))

flip = rnum <= temp

trues = np.logical_xor(trues, flip)
```

Comment: Are you looking to add a particular type of noise to your samples? If you added Gaussian noise, with a small mean, you would mostly end up with the effect you're looking for. The further the value was from the threshold, the less likely it would change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you want to have an output vector with the following properties:

- boolean vector
- same number of elements as in the input vector
- probability of each element being True depends on its value w.r.t. threshold
- the number of Trues is the same as if we used a simple threshold

So, you need a probability function which tells the probability of each input value to give True for the output value. With plain thresholding the probability is 1 above the threshold and 0 below the threshold. You, however, need to have something softer.

Without the last requirement (number of Trues) for the output vector, the algorithm would be very simple. The probability function output would be compared to random valuess between 0 and 1, and that would be the result. Depending on the input signal distribution and the probability function this may produce satisfactory results.

Just an example of this:

```
# threshold at 0.8, below 0.7 always false, above 0.9 always True, linear in between
def prob_f(x):
    return np.clip((x - 0.8) / .2 + .5, 0., 1.)


def noisy_threshold(sig):
    p = prob_f(sig)
    return p > random.random(sig.shape)
```

But if a better match for the number of Trues is required, we need to do something afterwards. We need a function which is given the desired number of Trues and the probabilities. Of course, doing this changes some of the properties of the resulting distribution, so there is no "clean" way of doing it.

One possibility would be to slightly adjust our probability threshold. For example:

```
def_ noisy_threshold(sig, threshold):
    # number of Trues with simple thresholding
    n_trues = np.asum(sig > threshold)

    # difference between random noise and our probability
    rdiff = prob_f(sig) - random.random(sig.shape)

    # sort the differences
    sortdiff = sorted(rdiff)

    # a new threshold is used so that the number of Trues is correct:
    return rdiff >= sortdiff[-n_trues]
```

This will return exactly `n_trues` Trues in case we are not so extremely unlucky as getting some exactly same random differences.